# JSP Portlets Flow

Tags: jsp, portlet

Im new to JSP Portlets.

I was concentrating on the flow of these Portlets and want to know:

- How does our first JSP page gets executed?
- How does doView() executed ? (Displaying the very first JSP Page)

I was assume it works like this:

**portlet.xml --> JSPPortlet(which extends Generic Portlet) --> doDispatch() --> doView()**

Is this flow correct?

If this is not correct Please let me know why

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is `render -> doDispatch -> do<Mode>` where the mode method called depends on the mode set in the `PortletRequest` (view by default). The `render` method is the only one exposed by the `javax.portlet.Portlet` interface.